# How to make day field optional in toLocalDateString

Tags: javascript, flot

I want to make day parameter optional in toLocalDateString as following:

```
if (item.series.xaxis.tickSize[1] == 'day') {
    var day_exist = 'day:"2-digit",';
}
else {
   day_exist = '';
}

dateString = d.toLocaleDateString(
    navigator.language, {day_exist month:'short', year:'2-digit'});
```

But this is not working. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not just add a variable to an object. You need to set the key.

```
var config = {month:'short', year:'2-digit'};

if (item.series.xaxis.tickSize[1] == 'day') {
      config.day = "2-digit";
}
dateString = d.toLocaleDateString(navigator.language, config);
```